# How to support my smart watch application on Sony SmartWatch

Tags: android

I have created a widget application for smart phone. Now i want to support the same application to sony SmartWatch. Any idea how to start or any sample code to refer.
Thanks in advance for Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have all the resources compatible to your smart watch. I mean resolution,density. Any android app will run on smartwatch.but the thing is that you can use only those apis that are supported for smart watch. You can run your app same as you are running on devices.